# Where do I have to implement the div tag? To not destroy the built structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, hugo

I'm building a portfolio with Hugo(SSG) and I want to use particle.js for my banner to look like in this web: https://nrandecker.github.io/particle/ , but I don't know how or where to implement the div tag:

```
<div id="particles-js"> </div>
```

In my already "built" welcome banner without messing all the structure.
Could you help me  figure out what changes I have to do to my css or index file for it to work as in the webpage I linked and still being responsive and everything? Thanks a lot in advance , I am not rlly experienced.
Edit:This is the what the code of the banner looks like:

```
<!-- Welcome Slider-->
<section class="hero-area" style='background-image: url("https://JavierSanchezRamirez.github.io/images/backgrounds/bg.webp")'>
    
    
    <img style="display: none;" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentElement.style.backgroundImage= 'url(https:\/\/JavierSanchezRamirez.github.io\/images\/backgrounds\/bg.jpg)'" src="https://JavierSanchezRamirez.github.io/images/backgrounds/bg.webp" />
    <div class="block">
        
        <h1>Welcome to my Portfolio</h1>
        <p>In this page you will find information about my skills, interests and achievements, as well as the projects I have been working on and contact information.</p>
        
        
        <a href="#team" class="btn btn-transparent page-scroll">Get to know me</a>
        
        
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /Welcome Slider-->
```

With Css:

```
.hero-area {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#particles-js{
background:#1a222c;
display:flex;
}

.hero-area:before {
  content: '';
  background: #1a222c;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hero-area .block {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.hero-area .block .video-button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #57cbcc;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.hero-area .block .video-button i {
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.hero-area .block h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .hero-area .block h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.hero-area .block p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-area .block .btn-transparent {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

You can find my css code here: [Css file](https://github.com/JavierSanchezRamirez/JavierSanchezRamirez.github.io/blob/master/css/style.min.css) and my index page here: [index.html](https://github.com/JavierSanchezRamirez/JavierSanchezRamirez.github.io/blob/master/index.html)
All the files can be found in : https://github.com/JavierSanchezRamirez/JavierSanchezRamirez.github.io

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service; you need to show your own attempt, post an [mre] that demonstrates where you're stuck. The particle plugin seems to be made for jekyll, so the main question is how compatible with hugo is it, if at all.

Comment: I have seen it being used in Hugo sites , I just have to place the scripts on the static folder. And okay I thought it was too much text but will edit it with where I failed. Thanks

Comment: if study position's in css fromm this link, you can solve your problem .https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp